# Remove first audio track from mkv file

Tags: audio, video, video-editing

I have an .mkv file with two audio tracks. I want to remove just the first one while keeping the second one, nothing else.

I've tried looking around in VLC, but I can't see how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FFmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/file.mkv -map '0:v' -map '0:2' -c:v copy -c:a copy /path/to/output.mkv
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!